# Accumulating a variable while updating dict values? (Trying to implement SGD + momentum)

Tags: python, tensorflow, list-comprehension, momentum, stochastic-gradient

So I have the following dictionary implemented for vanilla SGD:

```
        update_weights = dict(zip(weight_keys,
                                [grad_weight[key] -
                                 lr * convert_to_tensor(dx[key])]) for key in weight_keys)
```

I am trying to implement something similar with momentum, however, I am not sure how I would be able to accumulate the velocity term so that I can update it all at once in list comprehension terms:

```
v_(i) = mu * v_(i-1) - lr * convert_to_tensor(dx[key])
grad_weight[key] += v_i
```

does anyone have any idea how I might do this using list comprehension (using Tensorflow preferably)?

```
for key in weight_keys:
     v = mu * v - lr * convert_to_tensor(dx[key])
     update_weights[key] = grad_weight[key] + v
```

Comment: Why do you need this to be a list comprehension?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much faster? I'm asking to see if there's a way.

Comment: Why are you trying to implement this by hand? Just use [tf.keras.optimizers.SGD](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/SGD); it has a momentum parameter.

Comment: It's for a specific program where I keras optimizers do not achieve what I need.

Comment: It might be slightly faster, but not enough so that you should care about it.  I don't understand why programmers seem so obsessed with list comprehensions and putting everything on a single line.  If what you have works, then there's nothing wrong with it.  If it's not obvious how to get it into a comprehension, maybe the result will be hard to read even if you find a way.  Readability is important.  What you have now is very readable, and there's no reason not to use it.  But if you find a way to use a comprehension and have it be readable, then great!

Comment: ...but wait. You aren't creating a list at all in your example. If you aren't creating a new list, then you don't want to use a list comprehension.  It appears that what you'd want is a dictionary comprehension.